# Does the common HTTP server implementation decompress POSTed form data?

Tags: http, compression, gzip, deflate

If I GZip the a POST request form data, will a HTTP server decompress it, or it only works the other way (server -> client)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What web server are you using?  I'm assuming your doing the POST from within a program.  While it's possible send gzip'd data to a server, browsers don't do it, because the server doesn't usually advertise what encodings it accepts.  You can see what a server accepts with an OPTIONS command:

```
curl -iX OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 20 Oct 2009 00:54:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8a DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6 SVN/1.6.5          proxy_html/3.0.0
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS,TRACE
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
```

However, if you control both the server and the client, you can send whatever data stream you like.  For example, [Mercurial compresses everything](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WireProtocol) in both directions, but doesn't rely on the web server for compression/decompression.

Comment: My WebServer is IIS with running a ASP.NET web application.